# Is there a term for something whose name pretty much repeats what it is--as in University College or Avenue Road?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a term for something whose name just re-states what it is, as in University College (London) or Avenue Road (Toronto)?

Comment: I don't think "university"/"college" and "avenue"/"road" mean the same. Any particular reason why you ask this question?

Comment: It should be noted that "university" and "college" are not a synonymous as some might think, nor are "avenue" and "road".  They have grown to be synonymous in modern usage, especially in the US, but they were originally quite distinct.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia these are **tautological** place names. They are very common in Britain and anywhere else that many languages have influenced the names of geographical features.

[List of tautological place names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names)
Wikipedia

**Example**

Eas Fors Waterfall, Scotland ('Waterfall Waterfall Waterfall' in Scottish Gaelic, Norse and English)

Comment: Townsville and Back Forest Wood are further examples.

Comment: See also [Torpenhow Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill).

Comment: If you run *down Pendle Hill*, you really are saying 'hill' 4 times: 'down' is derived from 'ofdune' [off hill], and Pendle used to be Pen Hill [hill hill], with a prosthetic 'd'.

Answer (score -1):

"Redundant" springs to mind. According to the OED "(Of words or data) able to be omitted without loss of meaning or function." Though not specifically referencing names, the concept seems to apply. Superfluous may be equally useful.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to elaborate on your answer with reference/research you have done to make this answer. Please visit [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). I advise you to delete this answer.